# Étymologie de « mais » : Comment a-t-il évolué de « davantage » à marquer la différence ?

Tags: étymologie, conjonctions

Ma recherche initiale sur l'étymologie de [« désormais » (adv. de temps)](http://www.littre.org/definition/d%C3%A9sormais) m'a dévoilé une définition de **mais** comme « davantage », voir ci-dessous.

> **Dès**,           **or** ou **ore**, heure (voy. OR),          et      **mais** [=] davantage :
>
> mot à mot, dès l'heure en avant.

Ensuite, je me lance dans [l'étymologie de « mais »](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/mais#.C3.89tymologie) :

> [1.] (Xe siècle) Du latin [magis](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/magis#la) (« plus, plutôt ») [[Plus, davantage.]](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/magis#la)

La connotation de « magis », et de **mais** dans « désormais », me semble neutre.

2. Pourtant, en français moderne, « mais » peut servir [« à marquer opposition, restriction, différence » (cf la définition 3)](http://www.littre.org/definition/mais).

Donc, le sens de « mais », comment a-t-il évolué de 1 à 2 ? Est-il devenu opposé?

<sub>J'ai tenté de lire [l'étymologie du TLF sur « mais »](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/mais/1), dont la longueur et le manque de formatage m'ont rebuté.</sub>

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Je vous remercie avec effusion de vos rectifications ! Ne puis-je demander de laisser que l'espacement dans la citation de Littré, pour faire séparer chacuns des morphèmes ?

Comment: C'est perturbant et c'est presque illisible sur le site mobile. De plus ça ne respecte pas texte originel.

Answer (score 8):

Je ne sais pas si ceci répondra à votre question, et je ne suis pas spécialiste de l'étymologie (et le TLF m'est aussi difficile à lire qu'à vous, même reformaté), mais il me semble qu'on peut affirmer en résumé :

- Le **sens originel** de *mais* est celui de *magis* en latin : « plus, davantage ». Il me semble que c'est bien ce sens qui est à l'origine de *désormais*.
- Pour obtenir un effet d'opposition ou de restriction, il fallait originellement y ajouter la **particule de négation** (*ne*, *non*). On retrouve ces constructions dans les exemples du TLF, ou dans certaines expressions figées, comme « n'en pouvoir mais ».

> « Il les assura même de la bénédiction pourtant hypothétique de sa
>   mère et de la pensée affectueuse de Dabek Sariéloubal qui **n'en pouvait**
>   **mais**. » (René Fallet, *Le triporteur*, 1951)

- Au cours des siècles, la particule de négation a de plus en plus fréquemment été omise, le sens négatif restant dominant dans l'usage et l'idée d'opposition passant donc au mot *mais* lui-même. (C'est le même phénomène qui explique l'existence simultanée des sens négatif et positif de *plus*.)
- Finalement, le sens originel s'est perdu et le sens d'opposition est resté dans l'usage.

Comment: Quelques autres exemples de mots ayant  comme *plus* deux sens opposés :  *pas*, *personne*, *jamais*, *rien*.

Answer (score 1):

> Étymol. et Hist.
>
> ***I - Adverbe*. 
>  
>   A. Temporel**
>
> 1. 2e moitié xes. ja non... mais «jamais plus ... ne»; ca 1130 ja mais «à partir de maintenant et dans l'avenir», v. jamais;
> 2. a) fin xes. magis [+ imparfait du subj.]«à un moment, un jour (dans le passé)» (Passion, éd. D'Arco Silvio Avalle, 88); ca 1100 mais [+ fut.] «à l'avenir, désormais» (Roland, éd. J. Bédier, 543);
> 3. b) ca 1050 mais ... ne, ne ... mais «ne plus jamais, ne plus» (St Alexis, éd. Chr. Storey, 36: Quant veit li pedre que mais n'avrat amfant; 187: ,,Certes`dist il, ,,n'i ai mais ad ester`);
> 4. ca 1100 unkes mais ne [+ parfait] «jamais, jamais encore (durée indéfinie dans le passé)» (Roland, 2223);
> 5. 1130-40 desormais (Wace, Conception N.-D., éd. W.R. Ashford, 1302, v. aussi désormais);
> 6. ca 1165 hui mais, mais hui «à partir de maintenant, désormais» (Benoît de Ste-Maure, Troie, 2108 [+ fut.], 2275 [+ ind. prés.] ds T.-L.); id. ne ... hui mais [+ fut.] «ne ... plus» (id. 7943, ibid.);
> 7. id. toz jorz ... mais [+ fut.] «toujours (durée indéfinie)» (id., 2269, ibid.).
>
> **B. Quantitatif**
>
> fin xes. mais «davantage» (Passion, 498); ca 1160 ne poöir mais «ne rien y pouvoir» (Eneas, 4390 ds T.-L., s.v. poöir); ca 1165 n'en poöir mais (Benoît de Ste-Maure, op. cit., 13164, ibid.).
>
> ***II - Conjonction.*
>
>   A. Adversative**
>
> 1. marque une opposition
>
> 1.a) 2emoitié xes. introduit une idée contraire à celle déjà exprimée (St Léger, éd. J.Linskill, 58 apr. une phrase négative; 113 apr. une phrase positive);
>
> 1.b) ca 1200 marque une préférence (Jean Bodel, St Nicolas, éd. A. Henry, 801: Pinchedé, hocherons as crois? − Mais a le mine, entre nous trois);
>
> 1.c) ca 1160 marque une précision, une rectification, un renchérissement apr. une interr. dir. (Eneas, 1754 ds T.-L.); ca 1200 (Jean Bodel, op. cit., 294: Soit pour un parti: a pais faire − Pour un? Mais pour canques tu dois);
>
> 2. marque une transition ca 1050 dans un récit «et voici que ...» (St Alexis, 213); ca 1100 (Roland, 1154);
> 3. dans un entretien assez vif, renforce une affirmation, une interr., un doute précédemment exprimés :
>
> 3.a) ca 1135 précède le verbe d'une prop. impér. (Couronnement de Louis, éd. E. Langlois, 2120: De quei le dotez vos? Mais chevalchiez et poignez tresqu'al pont);
>
> 3.b) 1176-84 [ms. fin xiiies.] introduit une intervention répondant à une mise en doute, un étonnement (Gautier d'Arras, Ille et Galeron, éd. A. G. Cowper, 3797, var. ms. P: Oïstes me vos ainc requerre se vostre pere ot rice tere U s'il ert besogneus d'avoir? − Mais voel je vostre pere avoir U vos amer por vostre pere?);
>
> 3.c) 1178 introduit la réponse à une interr. précise (Renart, éd. M. Roques, 13257: ,,Avroie ge poisons assez Tant que seroie respassez De cest mal qui m'a confondu?`Et Renart li [Ysengrin] a respondu ,,Mais tant con vos porrez mangier`).
>
> **B. Restrictive**
>
> 1. mais que «à l'exception de» fin xes. apr. une phrase positive (Passion, 99); ca 1050 apr. une phrase négative (St Alexis, 37);
> 2. ne mais que «id.» ca 1100 apr. une phrase négative (Roland, 1934); apr. une phrase positive (ibid., 217).
>
> **C. Hypothétique,** exprimant la supposition, la condition ca 1100 mais que + subj. «pourvu que, à condition que» (ibid., 234).
>
> **D. Concessive** ca 1165 mais bien + subj. «bien que, même si» (Benoît de Ste-Maure, Troie, 8621 ds T.-L.); ca 1170 mes que bien + subj. (Chrétien de Troyes, Erec, éd. M. Roques, 4684).
>   De l'adv. lat. magis «plus, davantage» employé notamment pour exprimer le compar. (en remplacement des formes synthétiques pour les adj. en -eus, -ius, -uus; dès l'époque pré-class. pour marquer une oppos., une mise en relief de l'adj. [cf. disertus magis quam sapiens, Cic., Att., 10, 1, 4], le tour périphrastique devenant de plus en plus fréquent à basse époque sans valeur expressive particulière), d'où mais adv. quantitatif (I A), et, appliqué à une quantité de temps, adv. temporel, le plus souvent combiné à d'autres adv. de temps (I B). Du sens secondaire «plutôt», notamment dans les tours non ... sed magis, ac magis, magis autem (TLL, s.v., 68, 1 sqq.), est issu l'emploi adversatif [cf., d'abord dans la langue poétique Catulle, 68, 30: id. ... non est turpe magis miserum est; en prose dep. Salluste, Jug., 96, 2: ab nullo repetere [sc. beneficia] magis id laborare ut...] (II A), ses représentants rom. (FEW t. 6, 1, p. 31b) montrant que magis avait dès l'époque prérom. assumé les emplois de sed (oppos. forte) et de autem (oppos. faible); pour sa part, à partir du m.fr., mais empiétera de plus en plus sur ainz (employé surtout dans les antithèses dont le premier terme est négatif, pour énoncer le second sous une forme positive, Ph. Ménard, Synt. de l'a.fr., § 309, 3orem.; G. Moignet, Gramm. de l'a. fr., p. 335) qu'il finit par supplanter.
>   L'emploi restrictif (II B) semble issu du tour compar. «pas plus ... que» [non magis ... quam], d'où «seulement; rien, si ce n'est que» [ne ... mais que; mais que], v. Lat. Gramm. t. 2, Syntax und Stilistik, p. 497, § 268 Zusatz
>
> 2. De l'emploi restrictif seraient issus l'emploi hypothétique (II C): «seulement, excepté, mis à part» d'où «sous la réserve que, à condition que, pourvu que» − et l'emploi concessif: «mis à part le fait que», d'où «sans tenir compte du fait que, bien que», v. Ph. Ménard, op. cit., §§ 263 C, 270 c, 273; v. aussi FEW, loc. cit., p. 32a et b.

---

Si vous copiez/collez la page du TLF dans une page LibreOffice, vous pouvez garder la typographie originelle, la formater  et même souligner les différentes acceptions de *mais* et suivre leur évolution.
 Il en ressort que le contexte détermine le sens.

Le *§ D* devrait répondre à votre question.

Comment: +1. Merci. Quant au problème avec le fouillis de TLF, consultez http://superuser.com/q/958753/269574.