# Comment « n'en pouvoir mais » a-t-il evolué pour signifier « ne rien pouvoir » ?

Tags: étymologie, négation, adverbes

[Cette réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/14401/1995) a entamé cette locution verbale, qui est expliquée [ici](http://www.expressio.fr/expressions/n-en-pouvoir-mais.php) d'où je cite partiellement :

> #### N'en pouvoir mais
>
> [...] Mais pour la comprendre, il faut savoir que cette forme est très ancienne, puisqu'elle date du XIIe siècle, à un moment où 'mais' était aussi un adverbe.
> Ce mot vient en effet du latin 'magis' qui signifiait 'plus' ou 'davantage'. Littéralement, la locution signifie donc "**n'en pouvoir davantage / pas plus**", sens resté bien vivace jusqu'à aujourd'hui, malgré la disparation de l'usage adverbial de 'mais' sauf dans cette expression. [...]

Comment associer mais avec la locution verbale en gras? Je pense que le suivant reste le même: pouvoir et ne (comme le seul adverbe négatif, suivant la 1e étape du [Cycle de Jespersen](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_de_Jespersen)). pouvoir.

1. « en » : À quoi correspond ce pronom ? Est-ce que [son étymon latin](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/en#.C3.89tymologie)  *inde* (« de là ») aide ?
2. « mais » :  Cet adverbe, correspond-t-il à seulement **davantage** ? Ou à **PAS davantage** ?
   À savoir, a-t-il déjà évolué pour ajouter un sens ultérieur négatif (de différence ou opposition), à sons sens antérieur de seulement **davantage** ?

Answer (score 2):

1. ***En*** vient bien du latin *inde* et signifie ici ***de cela***. Il s'est écrit *ent* en ancien français. Il remplace un complément d'objet direct absent comme *Je n'en veux plus* veut dire *Je ne veux plus de cela*, *Je n'en peux plus* veut dire *Je ne peux plus (supporter) tout cela*
2. Comme la plupart des adverbes utilisés dans les tournures négatives, la perception du sens de **mais** est ici l'inverse de la signification originale de ce mot (plus).

*Je n'en peux **mais*** = *Je n'en peux **plus***.

La même inversion se retrouve avec **rien**, **pas**, **personne**, **jamais**, **plus**, **point**, **aucun**, **guère**...

Comment: Merci. Pourriez-vous répondre à ma question 1 aussi, ou devrais-je la poser séparamment ?

Comment: C'est fait. --jlliagre